# How to get cohen's d value after doing ANCOVA?

Tags: r, ancova

I have a dataset that I ran ANCOVA on and did postHoc analysis.
when I view the summary of my data by typing summary(data),
I only see the t value and p value.

Is there a way I can see cohen's d value on this?
Am using the R stats package.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit the question with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Answer (score 1):

#### A Note on Effect Sizes

Greetings! First off, you would never use Cohen's d for an ANCOVA. A much more common effect size for ANCOVA is eta squared or partial eta squared. Additionally, I didn't see you post any code or data, so it is hard to guess exactly how you have run your model so far. I can run a model with some data you can use in case you want to at least know how, but next time provide the `dput` of your data in your question along with your code you have run so far.

#### Running the ANCOVA

First we can load the `effectsize` library to obtain our eta squared estimate and load our data with minor changes.

```
#### Library ####
library(effectsize)
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)

#### Load Data ####
data(obk.long,
     package = "afex")

#### Modify Data ####
obk.long <- obk.long[1:240 %% 3 == 0, ]
obk.long$id <- seq_len(nrow(obk.long))
```

If we look at the data, we can check to see that it is appropriate (at least on the surface) for ANCOVA:

```
#### Inspect Data ####
glimpse(obk.long)
```

Here you can see the data from this command:

```
Rows: 80
Columns: 7
$ id        <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1…
$ treatment <fct> control, control, control, control, control, control…
$ gender    <fct> M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, F, F, F…
$ age       <dbl> -4.75, -4.75, -4.75, -4.75, -4.75, -2.75, -2.75, -2.…
$ phase     <fct> pre, post, post, fup, fup, pre, post, post, fup, fup…
$ hour      <fct> 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4…
$ value     <dbl> 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 2, 5…
```

We can then fit an ANCOVA with this model:

```
#### Fit Data to ANCOVA ####
fit <- aov(value ~ gender + phase + treatment, 
          data = obk.long)
summary(fit)
```

Here you can see the summary from the model:

```
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
gender       1   9.11    9.11   2.932    0.091 .  
phase        2   3.06    1.53   0.493    0.613    
treatment    2  81.04   40.52  13.037 1.41e-05 ***
Residuals   74 229.98    3.11                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

We can also look at our pairwise comparisons with this code:

```
#### Tukey PWC ####
tukey_hsd(fit)
```

As seen here:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 9
  term     group1 group2 null.…¹ estim…² conf.…³ conf.…⁴   p.adj p.adj…⁵
* <chr>    <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  
1 gender   F      M            0   0.675  -0.110   1.46  9.1 e-2 ns     
2 phase    fup    post         0  -0.125  -1.18    0.929 9.57e-1 ns     
3 phase    fup    pre          0  -0.531  -1.82    0.760 5.89e-1 ns     
4 phase    post   pre          0  -0.406  -1.70    0.885 7.33e-1 ns     
5 treatme… contr… A            0   2.04    0.773   3.30  7.14e-4 ***    
6 treatme… contr… B            0   2.21    1.10    3.31  2.56e-5 ****   
7 treatme… A      B            0   0.170  -1.01    1.35  9.37e-1 ns     
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​null.value, ²​estimate, ³​conf.low,
#   ⁴​conf.high, ⁵​p.adj.signif
```

#### Obtaining Partial Eta

From there you simply run this code:

```
#### Run Effect Size ####
eta_squared(fit,
            partial = T)
```

Which gives you the effect size:

```
# Effect Size for ANOVA (Type I)

Parameter | Eta2 (partial) |       95% CI
-----------------------------------------
gender    |           0.04 | [0.00, 1.00]
phase     |           0.01 | [0.00, 1.00]
treatment |           0.26 | [0.12, 1.00]

- One-sided CIs: upper bound fixed at [1.00].
```

#### Side Note

There are a number of things you should check with an ANCOVA before running it or obtaining a summary from the model. It is best to make sure it fits all model assumptions before interpreting results like effect sizes. Let me know if this was helpful.